# puppeteer/nodejs couldn't clean up its child processes when crashed

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

recently i'm using puppeteer to automatically fetch and save some web pages. chromium use suid chrome_sandbox as its sandbox.

the issue is that, sometimes the script crashes due to some stupid mistakes i made like use await out of async methods, or the system running out of resource. after the script crashed i found there was several chrome_sandbox still alive and retrieved by systemd, whose user is root because of suid.

a primary guess on the situation is that, node.js may send sigkill to its child processes so that chromium process are killed immediately. but because chrome_sandbox is run by root, node.js could fail to send the signal SIGKILL and got 'permission denied'.

i'm wondering is there any way the script can close chromium properly in any situation? and how on earth does node.js handle the situation that it has an exception and has a child process? does it send sigint sighup sigkill or sigterm? i'm very confused about that.